# Instagram Graph API to publish content

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have used the `Instagram Graph API` to publish posts on `Instagram` based on it's [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/). I use this API as below to upload an image:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/17841401176636063/media?image_url=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg&caption=%23BronzFonz&access_token=IGQVJXMG9GZAlgtN0ZAGQzYxcm5GQzRUTl9pbENRSWU1NjVGeE81clJ4RHVJMlU4aVk3cnhibDdKaVVidUxpcmFnWl9qaDU3alFFeWtVS01MNE9uRnBqLXVjLVF1S0tqa3lRaHJyYDRn
```

And I get this result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 190,
        "fbtrace_id": "Ac6EIeqwzInWWyWs7H0jKhc"
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my request?I am sure about the access token, I get it from `https://graph.instagram.com/access_token` and it is my long-lived access token.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add "instagram_content_publish" as a scope?

```
https://www.facebook.com/v16.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&display=page&redirect_uri=https://example.com/success&extras={"setup":{"channel":"IG_API_ONBOARDING"}}&scope=instagram_basic,instagram_content_publish,instagram_manage_comments,instagram_manage_insights,pages_show_list,pages_read_engagement&response_type=token
```